# Cannot pass parameter from one decorator to other in NestJs

Tags: graphql, nestjs, decorator, typescript-decorator

I am using a ResolveField in my nestJs application and I have two decorator inside the function, I cannot pass the parameter from one decorator to another decorator

```js
  @ResolveField()
  async resolveTableName(
    @Parent() parentTableName: ParentTableType,
    @Args('input') input: PropertyResolveFieldFilter,
    @InjectLoader({
      fromEntity: childTableName,
      resolveType: 'many',
      fieldName: 'parentId',
      resolveInput: { where: { name: input.name } },
    })
    loader: DataLoader<string, ChildType[]>,
  ) {
    return await loader.load(parent.id);
  }
```

i can't use the input from @Arg decorator inside the @injectLoader(in the where condition)

Comment: Is inject loader custom decorator ? If so can you provide code for it ?

Comment: i use injectLoader from @keyvaluesystems/nestjs-dataloader